# Como instalar LLVM?

Tags: c, clang, llvm

Como instalo o clang/LLVM no windows para correr programas C em bash se aparece sempre "failed to find msbuilt toolsets" quando instalo o llvm??

Comment: [MSBuild Toolset (ToolsVersion)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb383796.aspx)

Comment: Não consigo instalar o clang, pelo que percebi essa pagina ajuda a integrar num projeto

Comment: Veja essa [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696948) feita no **SO** e a [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42697374/8353154) dela.

Answer (score 1):

Pode baixar os instaladores para windows em: http://releases.llvm.org/download.html

No caso tem duas versões:

- http://releases.llvm.org/5.0.0/LLVM-5.0.0-win32.exe
- http://releases.llvm.org/5.0.0/LLVM-5.0.0-win64.exe

> Para versões mais recentes acesse o link citado no começo

Note que no momento da instalação irá aparecer a seguinte tela:

[image: llvm instalação]

Selecione como deixei no exemplo, pode trocar para *All Users* se desejar, o icone no desktop é opcional, mas pra facilitar pode deixar lá.

> **Nota:** É provável que tenha que instalar o http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools, se ainda não tiver instalado.

---

Depois de instalado pra testarmos apenas, crie um arquivo na pasta que desejar com nome `hello.c`, então adicione isto nele:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Stack Overflow");
    return 0;
}
```

Então via CMD ou PowerShell navegue até a pasta, algo como:

```
cd c:\pasta\aonde\salvei\meu\programa
```

Então digite isto e aperte Enter:

```
clang hello.c -o hello.exe
```

Depois no CMD digite isto:

```
hello.exe
```

Se tudo correr bem irá aparecer o texto:

> Stack Overflow

Exemplo de teste no meu computador:

[image: hello world com clang]